# Initializing a trait attribute while using the cake patern

Tags: scala, initialization, traits, cake-pattern

Is it possible to initialize an attribute in an enclosed trait of a cake pattern? Something similar to early initializers. For example:

```
object CakePatternInit {

  trait A {
    var prop: String = null
  }

  trait A1 extends A

  trait B {
    this: A =>
    println(prop.toUpperCase) // I'd like here prop to be initialized already with "abc"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val b = new B with A1
    //  how do I initialize prop here?
    //  can I write something like this:
    //  val b = new B with { prop = "abc" } A1
  }
}
```

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359022/scala-trait-member-initialization-use-traits-to-modify-class-member/35359899#35359899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  trait A {
    def prop: String
  }

  trait A1 extends A

  trait B {
    this: A =>
    println(prop.toUpperCase) // I'd like here prop to be initialized already with "abc"
  }

  val t = new B with A1 { def prop = "Hello"}
  > HELLO
  > t.prop
  res22: String = Hello
```

Declare your `prop` as method, because **scala** can't override **var**'s

There is an article that can help you: [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)

Comment: more info here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html